# Does the Fog Cloud spell work in conjunction with the Blind Fighting fighting style the way I think it does?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, vision-and-light, fighting-style

The description of the [*Fog Cloud*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) spell says:

> You create a 20-foot-radius sphere of fog centered on a point within range. The sphere spreads around corners, and its area is heavily obscured. It lasts for the duration or until a wind of moderate or greater speed (at least 10 miles per hour) disperses it.

Now, based on the "heavily obscured" part specifically, I chose the "Blind Fighting" Fighting Style:

> You have blindsight with a range of 10 feet. Within that range, you can effectively see anything that isn't behind total cover, even if you're blinded or in darkness. Moreover, you can see an invisible creature within that range, unless the creature successfully hides from you.

So the idea is that if I cast Fog Cloud, that will cause the enemy to have disadvantage against me, but I won't be disadvantaged by them? Does that work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### That is the basic premise

You missed the definition of [heavily obscured](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight):

> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the **[blinded](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded)** condition when trying to see something in that area.

Looking up blinded shows:

- A blinded creature can't see and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.
- Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage.

As the second bullet states, "the creature's attack rolls have disadvantage." So they are outta luck.

Now, normally, you'd have advantage (because the target can't see you) AND disadvantage (because you're also in the heavily obscured cloud and can't see the target)--cancelling each other out. But since your character has blind fighting, they do not rely on sight and therefore do not suffer disadvantage and can attack with advantage.

Answer (score 17):

### This works even better than you think

The fog cloud makes the area heavily obscured, which means (p 183 PHB):

> A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.

And the blinded condition (p 290 PHB) has this effect:

> - A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails
>   any ability check that requires sight.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and
>   the creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.

So other creatures will have disadvantage to hit you if you are in the fog cloud unless they also have blindsight.

Blind Fighting gives you **Blindsight** (p. 183 PHB):

> A creature with blindsight can perceive its surroundings without relying on sight, within a specific radius.

You can still perceive other creatures in the cloud, as you are not relying on sight. Not only will they have disadvantage to hit you, **you also get advantage on attacks on them**.

One member of our group employs a similar tactic with *darkness*. It is very effective.

*Fog cloud* in many respects is even better than *darkness*, because it only costs a first level spell, not a second level spell, and because it is more reliable: there are a number of monsters that can see in magical darkness (for example, devils with devils' sight), but they will still be blinded by fog cloud. Even truesight is blocked. Only monsters that also have blindsight do not suffer the effect.

There is however one big disadvantage for *fog cloud* vs [darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness): its location is static -- you will not be able to have it move around with you as you move in combat, and often combat is dynamic and requires you to move. If you want to be able to do that without losing the benefits of blind fighting, you could pick *darkness* instead, which you can cast on an object you carry such as your weapon so it can move with you. Blind fighting will work with that, too.

Comment: A good target for Darkness might be a small rock tied to your shirt with string, so you have the option of tearing it off and throwing the darkness somewhere, or leaving it somewhere (and sneaking out of it to fool your enemies) without disarming yourself.  If you have multiple daggers to spare, casting on an off-hand dagger could be fun if you throw it at a dangerous ranged attacker; it might take them a round or two to figure out that pulling out the dagger and throwing it away could get rid of the darkness surrounding them and stopping them from casting most offensive spells or aiming a bow

Comment: @PeterCordes If the dagger-thrower *misses* the target, it's even *better* -- it's much harder to find a dagger in the dark if it's not sticking in you!

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: Oh yeah, if a skilled dagger thrower can get it to stick into a wooden wall or ceiling, they can place it where they want.  A dart or something might work well if this is plan A for using this object; lighter compared to its length, so easier to get it to stick into wood even if it hits at a shallow angle.  (And requires much less skill to get it to hit point-first.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Who needs skill as long as it comes to rest within 10 feet of your enemy? Even I could manage that with a dart!